# Get a specific value from a header

Tags: python, pandas, header

I am trying to get a specific value from my header and use it later. The header I am having is: Weekly data: 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31.

I am trying to get only "2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31" from this header.

```
data_range=pd.read_excel("weekly data.xls")
data_range=date_range.columns.values
data_range=date_range.split(":")
print(data_range)
```

The data set looks like this:

| Index | Weekly data: 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Site Name |
| 1 | Site ID |

when I run the script above, I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'

Thanks!

Comment: and what's your issue?

Comment: when I run the script above, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: then you have to cast it to string, `str(date_range)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `date_range.columns.values` is an array you have to first isolate the array element to extract text.
Here is functionnal code

```
import pandas as pd

date_range=pd.read_excel("weekly data.xls")
print(date_range.columns.values[1].split(':')[1].strip())
>> '2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31'
```